# org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite primary key as a foreign key in another table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have problem with referencing to the composite primary key in one class from another, with `@OneToMany` annotation.

My class with composite primary key is below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "name_entry")
public class NameEntry {,

    @EmbeddedId
    private NameEntryPK id;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Composite Id class is like that:

```
@Embeddable
public class NameEntryPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "entry")
    protected String entry;

    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    //getters, setters
}
```

This is clear to me and its working perfect. The problem occurs in another place. I would like to have another class with foreign key to the `NameEntry` primary key. I have written something like that:

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "content_entry")
public class ContentEntry {

    //id, other columns

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name = "entry_content", referencedColumnName = "entry", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="title_name", referencedColumnName = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    protected NameEntry nameEntry;

    //getters, setters   
}
```

And according to this my exception is:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
Unable to find column with logical name: `entry` in
org.hibernate.mapping.Table(name_entry) and its related supertables and 
secondary tables
```

According to this: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7713?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel I have tried to surround the columns name with gave accents. But it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that the issue has anything to do with the case of the columnames, as it looks like your mapping is incorrect.  The join columns you specified indicate that there is a "entry_content" field that references a "entry" field, but you set up the reference so that it goes from "name_entry" to "content_entry".  So it is looking for a mapping for the "entry" field within the ContentEntry class and can't find one.  What I think you meant to put was that "entry" has a referencedColumnName of "entry_content".  Try switching them and seeing if that helps.

The mappings themselves though do not make much sense to me.  I don't see how ContentEntry can have many NameEntry if the foreign key being used is NameEntry's primary key - which will be unique.  Should it not be the other way around, that NameEntry can have many ContentEntry, while a ContentEntry has a ManyToOne relationship to a single NameEntry?  If not, you might want to describe what either the tables or object graph you want should look like and work from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have realized that in my case I should use `@OneToOne` annotation. With `@OneToOne` annotation I am still getting error, but the exception contains name of the `name_entry` not `content_entry` as previous. I will check switching column names as you have suggested me.

Comment: As I have changed relation type to `@OneToOne` the exception contains correct information: `Unable to find column with logical name: `entry` in
org.hibernate.mapping.Table(name_entry)`. So switching the column names at this moment is not a soultion. Do you have please another suggestions for me?

Comment: No, sorry.  Now that you've corrected the mapping, there doesn't seem anything obviously wrong that might cause this.  Try posting the full stack trace to see if someone can help with it

Comment: I have add `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` to the `@OneToOne` annotations and at this moment everything works perfect.